# HTML Email Form Error

Tags: html, forms, email, xhtml

In the following HTML form I am unable to derive the username. Is it because of using "ID" instead of "NAME"? Do suggest an alternative to overcome this problem.

```
   <form action="mailto:demo@demo" method="post" enctype="text/pain">
   Username:<input type="text" id="usr"/>
   Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
   </form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it because of using "ID" instead of "NAME"?

Yup. From the [manual](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html):

> A control's "control name" is given by its name attribute. The scope of the name attribute for a control within a FORM element is the FORM element.

Use the `name` property instead.

Answer (score 0):

**To access values you should use `names`**, modify your code like this:

```
<form action="mailto:demo@demo" method="post" enctype="text/pain">
   Username:<input type="text" name="usr"/>
   Password:<input type="password" name="pwd"/>
   <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

and then you can access those values by `usr` and `pwd` variables.

Hope this helps.